# Browser Auto Select file through File Input Tag via Browser Extension

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to auto select a file through
File input tag < input type=file >    via java script ?

I know this is security issue and not allowed normally.

But is this allowed through extensions or in any form in any browser,

because i m working on a automation project
which requires posting of a form with multiple values has 
upload feature which uploads file first and then posts form(kijiji.ca)

and need this to be done.

need not to be browser specific any browser which have automation capability like chrome, Fire fox

## Further reuquirement

Hi Wladimir, i got it working as Wladimir suggested in Extension scope.

Can u tell me if i need to auto select multiple files what value should i set.

I tried setting this

```
input.value = '"D:\Temp\step1.jpg" "D:\Temp\step2.jpg" "D:\Temp\step3.jpg"'
```

but it don't accept it. Though i can set it to single image and it takes it..

thanks..

Comment: Hi @wladimirpalant, just waiting for your answer on it..

Comment: Making this a conversation between you and another person really doesn't work two years later.  Please update your question to show what you have done so far.  But "" isn't legal syntax; I think you want "\"filename"\".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox extensions are allowed to set `input.value` property so something like this will work:

```js
input.value = "c:\\autoexec.bat";
input.form.submit();
```

However, when using Add-on SDK a content script will likely not have the necessary privileges (needs to be tested). In this case one would need to use [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) and access the web page directly rather than via a content script.

As to Chrome, extensions there don't have access to the file system - so the security restrictions that apply to web pages are applying to extensions as well. Allowing extensions to set the value of a file upload widget would be a security issue there. So I'm pretty sure that it isn't possible.

Comment: hey i tried it on FF 3.6 not working. i have this
< input id="s" type="file" >
when i set document.getElementById('s').value="E:\image1.jpg";
and check  document.getElementById('s').files
it returns 0 files

Comment: @SohanChotia: You shouldn't be testing anything in Firefox 3.6 - it's outdated and no longer supported by Mozilla. In particular, File API was still very new when Firefox 3.6 was released. In Firefox 12 this works, at least when you run it from a privileged context. `input.files.length` gives me 1 file and file name is correct.

Comment: What privilege should i do please can u give me the code.Thnx for ur help. I m running this code from overlay.js. 
Also i installed FF 12 now 
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    myExtension.init();
    alert('ss');
  }, true);

is not working, no alert displayed????

Comment: Hi i made it working files showing 1, but one problem there is onchange event attached to this input which is not firing. how to make it fire.

Comment: @SohanChotia: The `change` event only fires if the user changes `input` value. In your case you should dispatch that event manually ([`dispatchEvent` example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/dispatchEvent_example)). Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: hi as i m working on FF 12 every thing on Mozilla Help is outdated i think because as we open a help page all the sample code says syntax exception see here ([Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Cookies))

I want to just run a script on every page and 
receive a cross domain script by passing a cookie of a specific domain to XHR request and then  load the response on that page.
can u provide some code on jsfiddle.com for me. 
expecting help from u. Thanks.

Comment: @SohanChotia: A syntax error doesn't depend on Firefox version - it just means that you have an error in your JavaScript syntax...

Comment: Hi Wladimir, i just want to know the basic Firefox hierarchical or layered structure of the window objects like Firefox main window, then all the tab browsers, then the tab window, then the document window in it etc.... e.g in this paste [eg](http://pastebin.com/VYfC1van)