# Set <input type="file"> value in Firefox Add-on with javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, firefox-addon

I have the following scenario in front of me:

I am using Selenium to drive my browser to fill a few forms, which works really well.

Now I am at the point, where I also want to upload files via the given webform (can't change how it's processed, can only manipulate the Javascript/HTML/DOM). As I have found out, for security reasons the file upload window pops up right away, when clicking into the  field. And also manipulation via normal Javascript isn't possible. Makes sense as well...

I have found out though, that a Firefox Add-On is supposed to be able to do this. The closest I have come to an answer is [another Stack Overflow thread on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510593/browser-auto-select-file-through-file-input-tag-via-browser-extension). If I got this working for me, that would be awesome! :-) But unfortunately I didn't, yet...

Minimal example:

```
<form method="post" url="http://www.example.com">
<input type="file" id="fileInput"/>
</form>
```

when calling (from the console in Firebug)

```
document.getElementById('fileInput').value = "C:\\image.png";
```

in get "Error: The operation is insecure." which is what I expect.

When calling the same in a contentScriptFile in a Firefox Add-On (I am using the add-on builder to create it) the script simply breaks without an error. My indicator for that is, that I do see the alerts before, but none after that line

Now the question is not so much why I don't get an error, but:
1. Am I on the right track? Is this supposed to work?
2. How do I make this work? I am not sure whether the mentioning of the "chrome authority" in the above link is relevant for me. Do I have to extend the scripts privileges somehow? If so, how?

Thank you!
Sandro

P.S. When I tried to set the value via jQuery, Firefox crashed completely. 
P.P.S. At the moment this is only supposed to work on my personal machine, cross browser issues or similar things thus aren't relevant

Comment: As you're apparently trying to do it via Selenium, why don't you just use [its API](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bselenium%5D+%2B+%5Bfile-upload%5D) directly?

Comment: First of all, because I didn't even know that existed! :-)

Now I have investigated and run in either one of the following problems:
- sendkeys method --> with the original form it says, that the element doesn't support this. In the minimal form there are no errors, but other than a change of focus to the button of the input element, nothing is happening there either (I expected the path to appear)

Comment: - with the attachFile method --> always running into a timeout. I have tried in Firefox and Chrome. And also tried to launch the Firefox in Chrome mode, but when calling "*chrome" as the webdriver, it still opens Firefox

P.S. I am using the wrapper Selenium VBA right now

P.P.S. Will try to upload a source from the web next. Not a real solution, but maybe giving another hint

Comment: Nope, attaching the same file via a http:// URL doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

I have now found a solution, that works. Part of the problems seems to have been that I have been using the Selenium VBA wrapper. I then tried it with the C# implementation with a quick Powershell script and it worked like a charme.

Summary: 
Original goal: upload a file wit a given form using Selenium
Solution: use SendKeys method on the input element of type 'file' to give full path to file
Sample script in Powershell:

```
add-type -path C:\path\To\the\dll\on\your\harddrive\webdriver.dll
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver
#the following page contains an element <input type='file' id='fileInput'/>
$driver.Url = "http://pathToTheSite.com/fileUploadFormPage.html"

$element = $driver.FindElementById("fileInput")

$element.SendKeys("C:\Image.png")
```

Done!!! The file is attached and the form submitted in one go

Comment: It is a matter of thinking "How would a user change this value in the UI?" The user would have to type a value in the input to change it... So that is what you have to emulate in selenium. +1 for answering your own question!

Comment: Were you able to find a way to do it without the file browse dialog popping up?