# Uploading file without triggering the upload window, client side

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been searching all over and I can't find a solution, I know it is not possible for a website to automatically upload a file without user interaction, but, is it possible to upload a file without having to manually click on the upload button and search for the file, client side. I am sorry if I'm not clear since I do not have much experience in this field.

This is the page I have tried : http://www.jist.tv/create.php

[image: I basically been trying to make the page know what file im trying to upload without using this input window]

I basically been trying to make the page know what file i'm trying to upload without using this input window.

This is the script the page uses to upload the file : http://www.jist.tv/vendor/uikit-2.24.3/js/components/upload.min.js

Is there a POST message I can send?

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Since it is possible to automaticly submit a form, this would be a major security risk and therefor isn't possible. [W3: file select](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#file-select) If it's just for personal use, you might be able to do something with a Firefox Browser Addon. Chrome addons don't have access to the file system so that won't work. More info can be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510593/browser-auto-select-file-through-file-input-tag-via-browser-extension

Comment: Thanks for the help.